# edsdk - Make picture programmatically

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

How I can take a picture from my camera Canon EOS Rebel T3i/600D with edsdk 2.12? I want to take a photo from the camera programmatically using C#.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, you're talking about C++ but you've tagged the question as C#...

Comment: I have no ideas what I must doing. Everything I've seen so blurry and unclear. Where to begin i haven't understood.

Comment: OK, this isn't really the place to teach you how to program. You need to find a good tutorial on C/C++/C# and then come back when you have some grounding. Giving you the code to your question will not teach you anything if you do not understand the basics.

Comment: This is the problem find EDSDK tutorials. I need some sample of the working programm on C# using EDSDK. But I can't. That's all. And thank you. I found good tutorial only at the C++, but i didn't know C++.

Comment: You need to learn C++ then!

Comment: http://github.com/jossef/edsdk-wrapper